# PHP Search function

Tags: php

I am trying to create a search function that seraches my oracle database for a car.

I want to know where i put the request search function on the page in php script so that it grabs the search box field and sends it to the action php link to process the data.

```
<form name:"search" action="http://www.deakin.edu.au/~sjrem/ssss.php" method="post">
<h2> Search for a car of your choice </h2>   

<p>
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="search" /> </td>
</tr>

</table>                    <p>
<input type="submit" value="Search" /> 
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you want to fix your form name styntax:

```
<form name:"search"
```

to

```
<form name="search"
```

Add this field to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="search" />
```

In your PHP:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'search'){
  search();
}

function search(){
  $keyword = $_POST['search'];
  // run your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are your `input` elements in a table?  Use CSS to position them.

Secondly, in `http://www.deakin.edu.au/~sjrem/ssss.php`, you'll have to determine whether or not the form has been submitted:

```
if(isset($_GET["search"]))
{
  //Fire up the connection and go to town!
}
else
{
  //Do something else.  Or not.  Whatever floats your boat.
}
```